# Rails 3 - Foreign Keys - Strings vs Symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys

I am in the process of learning Rails and I've ran into an interesting problem tonight.

I was creating a migration that would require an index on the foreign key:
[image: Migration with Symbol]

Whenever I would run 'bundle exec rake db:migrate', I would receive this console error:
[image: Migration Error]

It looks as if it was trying to create the index ***before*** it was creating the reference.

The reason I believe this is because when I change the "subject" reference to a symbol:

[image: Migration with symbol instead of string]

The migration then suddenly works as expected!
[image]

This may just be the fact that I'm a total newby, but are symbols actually processed faster by Ruby than strings are?

Just curious - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a "faster" problem, or a problem of speed. The migrations are executed one line at a time, in order. The way you had it specified before simply didn't create the column correctly, hence when it got to the line where you create the index, the names didn't match up.

My guess is, with the string version it created the column name exactly as you spelled it, "subject" as opposed to `subject_id` when you use a symbol. Either way, you definitely had a name mismatch between when the column was created, and when the index was being built.

Always use symbols for this in your migrations, and you should be fine. Always check your `schema.rb` file, or browse the database using a GUI tool, after a migration to make sure the columns got created the way you expect, and with the data types you think they are, and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Just to see what would happen, I ran rake db:migrate VERSION=0 to go back to the original state (I checked it with the SQLite Manager add-in for FF).  Then I changed the text in the migration file to read "subject_id" instead of "subject".  I still receive the same error after migrating back up.  From now on, I will stick with the symbols, but it would be nice to know why it didn't work.  From what I've read "subject_id" should give me the same result as :subject.

Comment: Good question. I've always used symbols myself, so I'm not sure.